# When are variables shared among function calls in list-based high-level functions such as tf.scan and tf.map_fn in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow

I am wondering in which cases variables are reused rather than re-instantiated or when it causes an error when using high-level functions. Do I need `tf.get_variable` inside a `tf.variable_scope(.., reuse=True)` context to enable sharing, or are the variables always shared, even when created with `tf.Variable`?

Comment: This sounds like two questions to me: what's the behavior of the state in a device when session.run fails, and what happens with reusable variables at graph construction time. Which one are you asking?

Comment: I added the sentence about errors because, AFAIK, `tf.get_variable` fails, if the variable name is already defined and the scope context does not allow reuse.

Comment: You need at get_variable to get sharing from the scope, I believe.